# When to use System.Convert and when to use System.BitConverter

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me to understand the different between Convert and BitConverter. In the below example, the above two methods give me two different answer:

```
UInt64 x = 0x4028b0a3d70a3d71;

// Use Convert
double d = Convert.ToDouble(x);               // d = 4.6231392352297441E+18

// Use BitConverter
byte[] xArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
double d1 = BitConverter.ToDouble(xArray, 0); // d1 = 12.345
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These two methods are used for different purposes; `Convert.ToDouble(x)` is equivalent to a cast: `(double)x`; which can be useful if you need the integer value to be treated as a floating point value, say, for mathematical operations:

```
int x = 7;
Console.WriteLine(x / 3); // 2
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(x) / 3); // 2.3333333333333335
Console.WriteLine((double)x / 3); // 2.3333333333333335
```

*BitConverter* class is useful if you want to transmit the value over the network as a series of bytes; you'd use the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` on the sending side, and BitConverter.To*OriginalType*() on the receiving end:

```
double x = 12.345;
byte[] xArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);

// Send xArray to another system over the network

// ...on the receiving system, presuming same endianness:
double d1 = BitConverter.ToDouble(xArray, 0); // d1 = 12.345
```

Now, in your example, let's take a look at what happens to the value of `x` in both cases:

```
UInt64 x = 0x4028b0a3d70a3d71;

// Use Convert
double d = Convert.ToDouble(x);               // d = 4.6231392352297441E+18
```

`d` is a cast of `x` to `double`; in decimal form, 0x4028b0a3d70a3d71 = 4,623,139,235,229,744,497 = 4.623139235229744497+18 in scientific notation. No magic here, it's pretty much what you'd expect to happen. Onward.

```
// Use BitConverter
byte[] xArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
double d1 = BitConverter.ToDouble(xArray, 0); // d1 = 12.345
```

...what? well, let's see how the `double` type is stored in memory. According to [IEEE 754 specification for double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), the format is:

- first bit is a sign bit (0 = positive; 1 = negative)
- next 11 bits are the exponent
- next 52 bits are the significand (well, 53, but only 52 are stored)

Here's the binary representation of 0x4028b0a3d70a3d71, arranged into the 3 sections we need to consider:

> 0 10000000010 1000101100001010001111010111000010100011110101110001

The following formula is used to convert this storage format to an actual numeric value:

(-1)<sup>sign</sup> x (1.*b<sub>51</sub>b<sub>50</sub>...b<sub>0</sub>*)<sub>*base2*</sub> x 2<sup>exponent - 1023</sup>

Instead of going through this math manually, we can use this [awesome floating point converter](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/ieee-754.old/64bit.html); here's the snapshot of the result:

[image]

See the decimal result? 12.345, same as what you're getting with `BitConverter.ToDouble(xArray, 0)` - but certainly not the same as the casting operation performed by `Convert.ToDouble(x)`

Answer (score 0):

The first:
you convert **int hex** representation to double

The second:
you treat the value in x as a bit representation of a **double**, not integer.